# IPython Console correction in multi-line input

Tags: python, ipython

When entering a command in IPython console using multi-line input, like creating an instance of an object with several parameters, I might enter the parameters on separate lines like:

```
In [1]: post = Post("post title",  
   ...: "Author name",   
   ...: "This is the content and it is the last parameter");
```

However, while entering the post content I realize that I mistyped something in the post title on line 1 of my multi-line input.  Is there a way to go back and correct a previous line?

Alternatively, is there a way to simply abandon the input altogether and stop entering the command without python attempting to interpret my partially entered command?

Comment: Have you tried holding the left arrow key? Or hitting the up arrow? I'm pretty sure at least one of those works in IPython.

Comment: Also Ctrl-C should cancel your input.

Comment: I have no idea what I was doing wrong before - but the arrow keys do allow me to move the cursor anywhere and edit the input.